# Get filenames with specific string in Camel route

Tags: xml, routes, apache-camel, javabeans

I am new to this forum and Camel so please forgive my ignorance.

I am trying to get a filename which starts with a specific string, e.g. "TRNREX" and ends with ".xml" but obviously the part in the route as below doesn't work. It must be easy somehow but can't find my answer on the internet, could somebody please help me out?

fileName=TRNREX*.xml

Comment: You need consume file with specific name, right ?

Comment: Well, I need to consume a file starting with a specific string...

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
from("file:{{consume.folder}}?include=TRNREX.*\\.xml")
```

To filter consuming files by regex pattern use include parameter.

UPD: Thanks @Screwtape. For XML route config your pattern should looks like:

```
<from uri="file:{{consume.folder}}?delay=10s&amp;readLock=rename&amp;include=TRNREX.*\.xml&amp;exclude=.*\.camelExclusiveReadLock$"/>
```

Comment: Mmm, I can't get it done with the ( ), is it also possible like this?

Comment: <from uri="file:{{consume.folder}}?delay=10s&amp;readLock=rename&amp;include=TRNREX.*\\.xml&amp;exclude=.*\.camelExclusiveReadLock$"/>

Comment: Don't know how to help you. I tested your url and it works perfectly with any small or big file.

Comment: Try to debug GenericFileConsumer poll method, and look why your file cant be consumed.

Comment: Given that you are defining your route in XML you don’t want the double backslash before .xml. That’s only needed in Java dsl. A single backslash should work. You are requiring a literal backslash in the file name at present.

Comment: Yes, that's it! :) :)

Comment: Yeah mind that the include/exclude etc are using Java regular expression patterns